# TypeError when reading multiple dict values into scipy function

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a dataframe with multiple categorical features I'm trying to run the Kruskal-Wallis hypothesis test on. Right now I'm passing `y` for each individual value of each of these columns by gathering them into a dict first:

```py
# run h test on each categorical variable
alpha = 0.05
for c in X_categorical:
    samples = {}
    for s in set(d_test_data[c].tolist()):
        samples[s] = d_test_data["SalePrice"][d_test_data[c] == s].copy()
    stat, p = scipy.stats.kruskal(*samples)
    print(f"{c}: t-stat: {stat}, p: {p}")
    if p < alpha:
        print("reject null hypothesis", "\n")
    else:
        print("unable to reject null hypothesis", "\n")
```

But then I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-b25ef3aa14d5> in <module>
     19     for s in set(d_test_data[c].tolist()):
     20         samples[s] = d_test_data["SalePrice"][d_test_data[c] == s].copy()
---> 21     stat, p = scipy.stats.kruskal(*samples)
     22     print(f"{c}: t-stat: {stat}, p: {p}", "\n")
     23     if p < alpha:

c:\users\jpaul\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in kruskal(*args, **kwargs)
   5838         if arg.size == 0:
   5839             return KruskalResult(np.nan, np.nan)
-> 5840     n = np.asarray(list(map(len, args)))
   5841 
   5842     if 'nan_policy' in kwargs.keys():

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

What can I do so that the function will accept my inputs? I tried using `to_list()` to convert them from `pandas.Series` to lists before storing them in my dict. I still get the same error.

Comment: Not seen that error before, but from what it says, it implies that it cannot apply / use the `len` function on the args. How does, `d_test_data["SalePrice"][d_test_data[c] == s].copy()` look like?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal `print(d_test_data["SalePrice"][d_test_data[c] == s].copy())` prints out what I expected it would, a pandas Series with all the values of `d_test_data["SalePrice"]` for the value of `s` being used to index.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal actually, looks like some of those Series are coming back empty (some of the values for `s` have no observations in the data I'm guessing), I think that might be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to tell for sure, but when I look at the signature of [`scipy.stats.kruskal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kruskal.html), I would suggest not to pass

```
stat, p = scipy.stats.kruskal(*samples)
```

Since `samples` is a dict, `*samples` will pass the keys of your dict as sequential arguments. That's probably not what you want. Maybe you want:

```
stat, p = scipy.stats.kruskal(*samples.values())
```